# Showing that the integers localized at a prime, p, is a Euclidean Domain

Tags: integers, principal-ideal-domains, euclidean-algorithm

I want to show that the integers localized at some prime natural number $p$:

$$R=\Biggl\{\frac mn \in \Bbb Q ~\Bigg\vert~ m,n \in\Bbb Z,\ n\notin p\Bbb Z\Biggr\}$$

is a Euclidean Domain, but I can't figure out how to show that my norm function works.

I have $f:R\to \Bbb N$ defined as $f(\frac ab)=|a|$.
Could someone show me how $f$ is a Euclidean norm function?

Comment: I answered this [over here in more generality](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/1748047/11653).